# Java: ZipFileSystemProvider does not copying file in zip file

Tags: java, json, file, filesystems, zip

I wrote following code:

```
Path mainFile = Paths.get("schnittprofiles/16/4/29/5/", "main/Profil_BH_121_16_04_29_05.json");
        Path zipFile = Paths.get("schnittprofiles/16/4/29/5/", "main/Profil_BH_121_16_04_29_05.zip");

        Map<String, String> zipProperties = new HashMap<>();
        zipProperties.put("create", "true");

        if (Files.notExists(mainFile)) {
            Files.createDirectories(mainFile.getParent());
            Files.createFile(mainFile);
        }
        Files.write(mainFile, "ABCDEF".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

        URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipFile.toUri());
        System.out.println(uri);
        FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, zipProperties);

        Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("Profil_BH_121_16_04_29_05.json");

        Files.copy(mainFile, pathInZipfile,
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

The problem is, that the file `Profil_BH_121_16_04_29_05.json` will not be copied into `Profil_BH_121_16_04_29_05.zip`. That means I only get a empty `Profil_BH_121_16_04_29_05.zip`-file without the json-file in it.
Did i miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it by myself:

I forgot an try with resources-block, therefore filesystem is never closed and Files are never copied:

Path mainFile = Paths.get("Profil_BH_121_16_04_29_05.json");
    Path zipFile = Paths.get("Profil_BH_121_16_04_29_05.zip");

```
Map<String, String> zipProperties = new HashMap<>();
zipProperties.put("create", "true");
zipProperties.put("encoding", "UTF-8");

if (Files.notExists(mainFile)) {
    //          Files.createDirectories(mainFile.getParent());
    Files.createFile(mainFile);
}
Files.write(mainFile, "ABCDEF".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipFile.toUri());
System.out.println(uri);
try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, zipProperties)) {

    Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("Profil_BH_121_16_04_29_05.json");

    Files.copy(mainFile, pathInZipfile,
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```